# Display comments count display unnecessary information

Tags: disqus

I placed Disqus on my WebSite, and when i trying to display comments count, it display like this:
`0 и 0 Reactions`
I need just 0.
I didnt founded any options in settings page at my Disqus account, that can help me with this.
I have only `Comment Count Link` section, and don't have `Reaction Count Link` section.
Question: I need to make it looks like this: `0`, not like this `0 и 0 Reactions`
TNX

Comment: This should be fixed now, no need to do anything else.

Comment: Yes, i writed message to the disqus support and they said, that this whas bug or something else, so they fixed this :)